# Running Java code in Ubuntu 22.04 distributive

Tags: 22.04, java, database

I'm new in this field, and trying to do some tests using java in Ubuntu

I wrote a code in Java to connect my localhost mssql server and create a new database. the code is tested on windows and it's working expectedly, i copied pasted in Ubuntu server 22.04 server
compiled it using command: **javac db_connect.java**
ran the following command: **java db_connect**

once i run the following command **java db_connect** I'm getting the following errors

`Error: Could not find or load main class db_connect Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: db_connection/db_connect (wrong name: db_connect)`

my main public class name is db_connect.

what should I change in the code or add modules to try to run the compiled java file.

in advance thank you!

find the code below:

```
package db_connection;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class db_connect {
  void func1() {
    String url =("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;");
    String user="";      
    String password = "";
    try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password)) {             
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();        
      String sql1 = "create database TM_users";                         
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
      System.out.println("Database created successfully...");  
      
//check if DB Exists
      String checkDBName = "bd1";
      ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getCatalogs();
      boolean dbExists = false;
      while (rs.next()) {
        String databaseName = rs.getString(1);
        if (databaseName.equalsIgnoreCase(checkDBName)) {
          dbExists = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      rs.close();
      if (dbExists) {
        System.out.println("Database already exists.");
      }else {
        String sql = "CREATE DATABASE db_1";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Database 'db_1' created successfully.");
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Err =>" + e.getMessage());       
    }
  }
    
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    db_connect ob1 = new db_connect();
    ob1.func1();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were probably using an IDE on Windows that managed this for you. You shouldn't just have "copied pasted in Ubuntu server 22.04 server" and ran commands without testing whether they would work on Windows.

#### Option 1: Run it with the proper folder structure

1. Paste your code inside `/path/to/project/db_connection/db_connect.java`  . Don't put it directly inside `/path/to/project` .
2. `cd /path/to/project` . Not any subfolder
3. `javac ./db_connection/db_connect.java`
4. `java db_connection.db_connect`

#### Option 2: Remove the package declaration

If you don't want to change the commands you run, you can change the `package db_connection;`. This is a bad Java coding practice and assumes you don't have any other classes you need in the `db_connection` package. To avoid confusing errors, it's also better to convert the `class db_connect` to PascalCase.